# added code to permalink (URL)

Tags: plugins, permalinks

I have a wordpress with WP job manager/resume manager.
I noticed that if i add new resume from the front-end i get some code added to the URL and extra variables (candidate name & location as below:

> https://sanai3i.com/resume/service-**5g3aesxnw-ali-alexandria-**%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%B1/

But if i add new resume from the backend (from admin dashboard), I don't get the code and the extra variables in the URL:

> https://sanai3i.com/resume/service1/

Can someone help please how to remove the extra added code and variables from the URL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a question for the plugin developers. Contact them to get an answer for this. Questions about third party plugins are off topic on here.

Comment: can you please share URL from where i can add new from front-end?

Comment: You will need to comment out where the post is inserting from front-end may be it is coming from  class-wp-job-manager-form-submit-job under include folder

Comment: You will find out the function save_job you just need to comment out $job_slug[] variable where location and some variables are included.

Comment: hi this is the link for adding a new form, but you will need to register first, i didn't find the function in the submit resume php:

Comment: @Akram What's the name of the plugin?

Comment: You need to find out where it is coming from or give me the proper information which plugin you are using it is pro version or free.